# When I search API.mentions_timeline why are my results inconsistent?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm using three if statements to search my mentions for three specific phrases.  Some of the time matches are found but most of the time they are ignored.

I can't see anything out of place here.  When I use similar code with another Twitter account to search for different phrases those matches are always found.

Here's the python code that searches mentions & replies.  If the rest is needed for context let me know so I can edit my question.

```
def reply_to_tweets():
    print('retrieving and replying to tweets...')
    last_seen_id = retrieve_last_seen_id(file_name)
    mentions = api.mentions_timeline(last_seen_id, tweet_mode='extended')
    for mention in reversed(mentions):
        print(str(mention.id) + ' - ' + mention.full_text)
        last_seen_id = mention.id 
        store_last_seen_id(last_seen_id, file_name)
        if 'that\'s a million bucks' in mention.full_text.lower():
            print('replying about AirMiles')
            api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' Just swipe your AirMiles card to enter.', mention.id)
        if 'fruit is always so fresh' in mention.full_text.lower():
            print('replying about shopping')
            api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' Cassie, are you shopping?', mention.id)
        if 'i play to win gord' in mention.full_text.lower():
            print('replying about Sobeys and Safeway')
            api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name + ' And that\'s why it pays to shop at Sobeys and Safeway.', mention.id)
```

When someone tweets @ my account with *that's a million bucks* I expect python to reply with *Just swipe your air miles card to enter.*  Occasionally this happens but usually it doesn't.

When someone tweets @ my account with *fruit is always so fresh* I expect python to reply with *Cassie, are you shopping?*  Occasionally this happens but usually it doesn't.

When someone tweets @ my account with *I play to win Gord.* I expect python to reply with *And that's why it pays to shop with Sobeys and Safeway.*  Occasionally this happens but usually it doesn't.

Comment: You print out mention.full_text before you apply your comparisons.  Do you see text that should be matched by your comparisons? - you should show us your output. - from the output, it should be pretty obvious what's going on.

Comment: You miss my point.  When you run your code, you may or may not see a match cause a "replying about..." string to be printed, but you should ALWAYS see the text you're searching through printed, because you are printing that unconditionally.  So what I want to see is output where the string in **mention.full_text** is printed out, and so you can see that it should match, but then it doesn't.

Comment: Oh...really...NOTHING is printed?  If that's the case, then your **api.mentions_timeline** call is simply returning no values in those cases.  You say "Some of the time matches are found but most of the time they are ignored".  That's not true if you get no output.  If you get no output, then no matches were ignored...rather, there was nothing returned to match against.

Comment: Pardon me Steve.  I was working from memory and described the output poorly.  Unfortunately the wifi here is way to slow to connect to Twitter properly & test.  As soon as I can run it I'll update the question to show the output.

The mentions were printed followed by a description of what was done if a match was found.  When the matching text wasn't picked up by my code only the mention was printed.

Comment: Cool.  I want to see that case where the mention was printed but no match was printed.  If the text looks like a match should have occurred, then something really strange is going on.  You're doing the right thing with your print statements to try to figure this out.

Comment: Back home now with time to test.  Same code is now working after changing nothing.  Perhaps I ran into some sort of Twitter account limit while I was working the account heavily during testing.